# RGtk2 - opening graphics files fails

Tags: r, graphics

I am working through the JSS article 'RGtk2: A graphical user interface for R' and I am trying to read in a graphics file using approximately the script from the article:

```
image<-gdkPixbuf(filename= imagefile("D:/My pictures/Business images/ja_logo.gif"))[[1]]
window$set(icon=image, title="Hello world 1.0" )
```

However, desipte trying out a variety of graphics files in different locations I invariably receive the following:

```
> image<-gdkPixbuf(filename= imagefile("D:/My pictures/Business images/Call centre.jpg"))    [[1]]
Warning message:
In gdkPixbufNewFromFile(filename, .errwarn) :
  Failed to open file '': Invalid argument
```

I have tried using files in the working directory and those with complete paths, but am getting nowhere. Am I missing something embarrassingly obvious or is there a problem with the package?

UPDATE: I have tried reading in a png using the package PNG:

```
imfile <- readPNG("D://My pictures//Business images//ja_logo.png")
imfile
```

And this worked (or at least didn't return any errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem. Here is the solution. Change your code to

```
image<-gdkPixbuf(filename= "D:/My pictures/Business images/ja_logo.gif")[[1]]
window$set(icon=image, title="Hello world 1.0" )
```

The path you use is OK. Although I always avoid using path contains " " in my code.

Then it would run smoothly. The reason is `imagefile` only matches the images in RGTK2 packages. They, actually, don't need to claim it in the namespace file. The help file is misleading too. Here is the original function:

```
function (name) 
{
    system.file("images", name, package = "RGtk2")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is your operating system. The path on linux is looking like that (single /):

```
"Business images/ja_logo.gif"
```

While on windows is looking like that (double \):

```
"Business images\\ja_logo.gif"
```

Comment: Thanks Jot En, but \, \\, /, and // all fail to work and give the same error message. I have always thought it a really stupid differenceand that it wouldn't be beyond the wit of even the dimmest MS developer to accept either format (same for UNIX / Linux).